# Error in using model.fit in keras with custom train_step

Tags: python, list, keras, tuples, tensorflow2.0

```
BATCH_SIZE =32
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((question, ans)).shuffle(1000)
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
class EncoderDecoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self,vocab_input=1000,vocab_output=1000,BATCH_SIZE=32):
    super().__init__()
    #Encoder
    self.encoder_vector = tokens.TextVectorization(vocab_input,output_sequence_length=24)
    self.encoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_input,256)
    self.encoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512,return_sequences=True)

    self.attention = tf.keras.layers.Attention()

    #Decoder
    self.decoder_vector = tokens.TextVectorization(vocab_output,output_sequence_length=20)
    self.decoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_output,256)
    self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_output)
    self.decoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512,return_sequences=True)


  def loss_function(real, pred):
    mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(real, 0))
    loss_ = loss_object(real, pred)

    mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss_.dtype)
    loss_ *= mask

    return tf.reduce_mean(loss_)


  def train_step(self,data):
    loss =0
    input = p[0] 
    targ = p[1]

    input = self.encoder_vector(input)
    targ = self.decoder_vector(targ)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      input = self.encoder_embedding(input)
      enc_output,enc_h,enc_c = self.encoder_lstm(input)

      attn_output = self.attention([enc_output,enc_h])


      dec_h = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(attn_output, 1), dec_h], axis=-1)
      dec_input = tf.expand_dims([self.decoder_vector(['SOS'])]*BATCH_SIZE,1)
      predictions = []

      for t in range(1,targ.shape[1]):
        dec_input = self.decoder_embedding(dec_input)
        dec_output,dec_h,dec_c = self.decoder_lstm(dec_input,initial_states=[dec_h,enc_c])
        predictions = self.fc(dec_output)

        loss+=loss_function(targ[:,t],predictions)

        dec_input = tf.expand_dims(targ[:, t], 1)

      gradients = tape.gradient(loss,trainable_variables)

      self.optimezer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients,trainable_variables))

      self.compiled_metrics.update_state(targ,predictions)

      return {m.name:m.result() for m in self.metrics}

model = EncoderDecoder()
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()])

model.fit(dataset,epochs=10)

Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StagingError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-153-573fadf7e010> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(dataset,epochs=10)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

StagingError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    <ipython-input-151-46787da81d42>:33 train_step  *
        input = self.encoder_vector(input)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:897 __call__  **
        self._maybe_build(inputs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:2416 _maybe_build
        self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/preprocessing/text_vectorization.py:528 build
        if self._split is not None and not input_shape[1] == 1:  # pylint: disable=g-comparison-negation
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:870 __getitem__
        return self._dims[key].value

    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am trying to override the keras model train_step in my custom class.
question is set of English text questions and ans is their respective answers. They are of random length and are not padded as TextVectorization will add padding. So dataset contains question answer pair. Now I batch this and use model.fit.
The error is when assigning input = data[0] and targ = data[1] in train_step. I need help on how to assign the input and output in the train step for a batch.